# Prevent Line Break Before flalign* Block in Itemize Environment

Tags: equations, align, line-breaking, itemize

My question is similar to [Prevent line break before equation environment in enumerated list item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304829/prevent-line-break-before-equation-environment-in-enumerated-list-item), but I want to use an unnumbered left align block. (Like the poster of the linked question, I would like to avoid using the `IEEEtran` document class.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[(a)]
        \begin{flalign*}
            x &= y &\\
              &= z
        \end{flalign*}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I want the equation to begin right after the (a) label.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a top-aligned `aligned` (pun intended) environment:

[image]

Observe that `aligned`, unlike `flalign*`, does not initiate and terminate math mode by itself; instead,`aligned` must be embedded in a math-mode group (here: the group that begins and ends with `$` symbols).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[(a)]
        \begin{flalign*}
            x &= y &\\
              &= z
        \end{flalign*}
    \item[(b)]
        $\begin{aligned}[t]
            x &= y \\
              &= z
        \end{aligned}$
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```