# Left alignment and no line break of equations in enumerate items

Tags: equations, align, amsmath, enumerate, flalign

What i try to make work is effectively combining this question: [Prevent line break before equation environment in enumerated list item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/304829/258117)(to have the equation on the same line as the label) with this question: [How can I use an align environment flush left?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28650/258117) (Have the equation all the way on the left).

This turns out to be not as easy as combining the solutions. I have a MWE here:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
    \item \mbox{} \vspace*{-\baselineskip} \[\begin{alignedat}{2}
                  \frac{1 - j}{1 + 2j} + \frac{1 + 3j}{1 - 2j} &= -\frac{6}{5} + \frac{2}{5} j
              \end{alignedat} \]
    \item \mbox{} \vspace*{-\baselineskip} \begin{flalign*}
              \frac{1 - j}{1 + 2j} + \frac{1 + 3j}{1 - 2j} &= -\frac{6}{5} + \frac{2}{5} j &
          \end{flalign*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The original equation is longer which is why there are still `&` delimiters at the `=` sign.

The problem here is now that for whatever reason the `flalign*` environment ist not in line with the item label even though it has the same `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` in front.
Does `flalign*` add more vertical space than the normal `equation*` environment and if yes how much is it exactly?

Comment: For   single -line equations, why do you use alignedat or flalign*?

Comment: @Bernard Because the whole equation is around 3 to 4 times longer than the MWE there and is running off the right page side otherwise

Comment: I see, You could simply use  $\displaystyle\begin{aligned}… \end{aligned}`. Another possibility would be to use the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`and make the list by hand, like this: `\beginfleqn}\begin{align*}&a)&……\end{align*}{\end{fleqn}`.

Comment: Unfortunately both of those ideas didn't work for me. ` $\displaystyle\begin{aligned}… \end{aligned}` vertically centered the whole equation to the label instead of having the first line aligned to it. The `nccmath` idea produced the same output as `flalign*` idea.

Comment: But while checking the documentation of `nccmath` i stumbled upon the `\abovedisplayskip` and `\abovedisplayshortskip` and it looks like `flalign*` adds a `\abovedisplayskip` before the equation. Adding `\vspace*{-\abovedisplayskip}` to the `flalign*` idea it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on @Bernard's earlier suggestion: To get the first row of a multi-row `aligned` environment aligned [pun intended] with the external marker, just use the optional `[t]` positioning specifier, as in $\begin{aligned}[t] ... \end{aligned}$.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
    \item $\begin{aligned}[t]
              \frac{1 - j}{1 + 2j} + \frac{1 + 3j}{1 - 2j} 
                 &= -\frac{6}{5} + \frac{2}{5} j \\ 
                 &= \text{some additional thoughts\dots}
           \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why was it that easy :D. Thank you so much for pointing out the `[t]` option.